# Using page's jquery in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension to modify a web page.

My target page already has jQuery. Is there workaround to use page's jQuery for my extension's user script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible as a content script.

possible if you instead inject the script (explained in the official docs).

not sure why you would want to reuse the library as its lightweight and locally stored.

Comment: Page already has jQuery, it's loading everytime when opening page. And I can do it with console. So why would I store it same thing in locally?

Comment: because they are in separate environments. console isnt. when the page upgrades jquery it will break you. thats why you keep yours separate. the local one loading incurs minimal weight.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you cannot. However, if you are using jQuery just to select elements try using `document.queryselector`